# what is the difference between pituitary dwarfism and thyroid dwarfism?

Tags: endocrinology, human-physiology, growth

My book ([Comprehensive Biology class XI, by J P Sharma](https://goo.gl/images/5pvOQf) ) mentions of two kinds of dwarfism- "Pituitary Dwarfism" and "Thyroid Dwarfism" but does not provide any details about the matter. so please help me.

Comment: Did you do and searches of your own (what did you find when you Googled the terms?) Please share what you found, then someone might fill in the details which are missing.

Comment: How can this be a homework question? The matter is quite confusing so I asked that. :O :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pituitary Dwarfism is a condition where less amount of growth hormone results in abnormally slow growth and short stature. Growth hormone is released under the influence of hypothalamic growth hormone-releasing hormone(GHRH), and is inhibited by hypothalamic somatostatin. Growth hormone deficiency has different negative effects if happens according to age it manifests;  in newborn, the primary manifestations may be hypoglycemia, while in later infancy and childhood, growth failure is more likely. Growth hormone deficiency can be congenital or acquired. It is usually permanent, sometimes transient.

Thyroid dwarfism is a condition arising from the deficiency of a thyroid hormone. It happens when there is lesser thyroid hormone secretion (defect of manufacturing or lesser supply of Iodine) before attaining the full development congenitally. It causes retarded growth and development of bones with disproportionate body proportions (that's dwarfism ).